# How to catch the button elementId as a parameter into a function

Tags: javascript, webforms

I want to add three buttons on a web form. Each button has its own id. When I click a button, I want the content of a div to become visible and others to be hidden. However, now I use three functions that add as an event to each button. Is there a smart way to create one function and add the elementId as a parameter? I want to "trap" the requesting object.

```
function myCoolFunction(parameter) {
if(parameter=="button1") {
  hilight("button1");
}
if(parameter=="button2") {
 // do something else for example
}

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You should use something like jQuery for this. It's a framework that does these things for you, like hiding and all.

Comment: I am using JQuery, I just want to be become more proficient with JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't it `highlight("div1")` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button1" onClick="myCoolFunction(this.id);" />
```

Comment: +1 This is the basic way of connecting events to functions. "onClick" should be "onclick" though.

Answer (score 1):

Using [custom data attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml)

**Markup**

```
<input type="button" value="button one" onClick="myCoolFunction(this)" data-related-div="div_one" />
<div id="div_one" />
<input type="button" value="button two" onClick="myCoolFunction(this)" data-related-two="div_one"/>
<div id="div_two" />
<input type="button" value="button three" onClick="myCoolFunction(this)" data-related-div="div_three" />
<div id="div_three" />
```

**Script**

```
function myCoolFunction(button) {
  highlight(button.dataset.relatedDiv);
}
```

Note that if you add a new button you don't have to modify the javascript code.

Also, this might break in crappy browsers (e.g. IE).

Update (for those who didn't follow the original link):

The `dataset` attribute is (at the moment) Webkit only. Custom attributes can be accessed using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` in all modern browsers though.

Comment: I had to vote this down. What in the heck is dataset? That sounds like a .NET specific thing. Granted he's using WebForms, but does .NET place a dataset in all elements?

Comment: @mwilcox: Please do some googling and don't downvote things just because of your own ignorance http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Sorry Pablo, but my ignorance has been trumped by your bad answer. You imply that your solution might not work in IE, but fact is, it doesn't work in any browser. Shyam indicated he wanted to learn JavaScript, so forcing a jQuery solution on him doesn't qualify. For those who don't drink the jQuery Kool-Aid: http://bit.ly/fL1vGY and http://bit.ly/hnlJNj

Comment: Please do try the code (is not that hard) before making a bold statement like **it doesn't work in any browser**. This works fine in Safari, Chrome and support in other browsers is probably coming (for the `dataset` attribte. You can always use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` in **every modern browser**). I don't know why you mention jQuery since I've written no jQuery code. Stop embarrassing yourself

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in jquery...

html

```
<div id="box_1"></div>
<div id="box_2"></div>
<input type="button" data-id="box_1" />
<input type="button" data-id="box_2" />
```

js

```
$("input:button").click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id"),
    boxes = $(".boxes"),
    boxes.hide().filter("#"+id).show();
    e.preventDefault();
})
```